# ORMLite id is always null (does not have an id field)

Tags: java, android, database, orm, ormlite

Can't for the life of me figure this out.
So in my request object I have

```
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "ID", canBeNull = false, generatedId = true)
private int entityId;
```

Whenever I do my insert method like this:

```
public void insert(T object) throws SQLException {
    DatabaseConnection connection = objectDao.startThreadConnection();
    Savepoint savepoint = null;
    try {
        savepoint = connection.setSavePoint(null);
        objectDao.createOrUpdate(object);
    } finally {
        connection.commit(savepoint);
        objectDao.endThreadConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

I always get a error like this

```
Class class UnsyncTripRequest does not have an id field
```

I'm not sure why I get this as from what I understand the id should be auto created?
I see in OrmLites BaseDaoImpl class there is an extractId method that has this line:

```
FieldType idField = tableInfo.getIdField();
```

Which is always null. Anybody have any insight into how I could fix this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> `FieldType idField = tableInfo.getIdField();` ... Which is always null.

The problem seems to be your entity, not anything to do with the save-point.  Somehow the `tableInfo` that is being generated by the DAO doesn't match your entity.  If the `entityId` field is in your class then I suspect that your `ormlite_config.txt` file hasn't been updated.

Comment: Hmm strange. I can't find any ormlite_config.txt file in my project. The entityId field is in my class but the weird thing is this works for another case

Comment: nah i don't see it

Comment: Are you obfuscating the class at all with proguard?

Answer (score 0):

You have both 'id=true' and 'generatedId=true' attributes set.  Can you please remove 'id=true' and see what happens?

Comment: `generatedId` implies `id`.

Comment: Do you have any association object?  How about this? @ForeignCollection(id = true)

Please see here: http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/ForeignCollectionField.html

Answer (score 0):

The Dao you are working on to create and update or delete, should be synchronised.
When you use

```
com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate()
```

ormlite extractId to see if that can be updated, then it goes and updates that particular row.

if there is a parallel thread deletes that row which has the id.

Ormlite throws java.sql.SQLException saying "**does not have an id field**"

Dao is access to table operation if that is synchronised, you should be good.

```
synchronized (objectDao){
                 objectDao.createOrUpdate(object);
            }
```